# Instantiating Typescript class from string parameters

Tags: typescript

#### (Optional) setup

Suppose I have an object with parameter names and their values, which are strings.

```
params = {
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": "value2",
    "param3": "value3",
    "param4": "value4"
}
```

and a Typescript class:

```
class SomeClass (... maybe implements some interface)  {
    param1: string;
    param2: number;
    param3: string;

    constructor(params){
        //Sets values appropriately
    }
}
```

#### Desired behaviour

- The class is constructed with the values from the object. They have to be changed to appropriate *types* within the class. Notice some params in `SomeClass` are `number`, but all the values in the object are strings. The class parameters can be of any class.
- If some parameter (in our case `param4`) is not declared in the class, it should either be ignored or raise some exception.
- Some parameters might be optional. Let's suppose `param1` and `param2` are optional in our case. Sometimes (this should perhaps be a separate question), if *one of* the optional parameters is not present, *some other one* has to be present. Is there an elegant way of implementing that?

#### Notes

- The setup is not fixed, and if there is a way to achieve this functionality using a different approach (implementing interface, extending type etc.), I can adapt to it.
- Assume there is a large number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) package, for example like so:

```
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

const someClassInstance = plainToClass(SomeClass, params);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Do you have any suggestions about the other points (optional/required checking)?

Comment: By default, all properties on the `params` object are set on the class, but you can change this behavior by using the `excludeExtraneousValues` option. If you want to get more advanced (skipping certain properties, etc.) it's all possible using different decorators described in their documentation.